# Как полностью удалить тег по его атрибуту

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Есть xml:

```
<items>
<item id="38648034">

<type>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</type>
<pages>030023</pages>
<language>EN</language>
<yearpubl>2019</yearpubl>
</item>

<item id="38676862">

<genre>статья в журнале</genre>
<type>научная статья</type>
<pages>111-122</pages>
<language>EN</language>
<cited>0</cited>

</item>
</items>
```

Если я хочу удалить тег в зависимости от его содержания, то делаю так:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('сентябрь2019.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p)

iterator = list(root.getiterator('items'))

for item in iterator:
    old = item.find('type')
    if old is None:
        continue
    text = old.text
    if 'статья в сборнике трудов конференции' in text:
        parent_map[item].remove(item)
        continue

tree.write('del.xml')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как можно удалить тег по атрибуту? Например, я хочу удалить тег по `id="38648034"`. Желаемый результат:

```
<items>
<item id="38676862">

<genre>статья в журнале</genre>
<type>научная статья</type>
<pages>111-122</pages>
<language>EN</language>
<cited>0</cited>

</item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import chardet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('июль2019.xml', 'rb') as file_risc:
    file_read_risc = file_risc.read()
    result_risc = chardet.detect(file_read_risc)
    text_risc = file_read_risc.decode(result_risc['encoding'])
    #print(text_risc)

root_risc = BeautifulSoup(text_risc, 'html.parser')

for div in root_risc.find_all("item", {'id':'38648034'}):
    div.decompose()

print(root_risc)
```